# Use a variable with especial characters inside grep

Tags: bash, shell

What I'm trying to do is use the certificate name that I get it through our CI process as `egrep` search clause to find the code signing identity of that certificate. The code that does the searching looks like:

```
SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution: My Great Company, INC. (Alphanumeric_Here)"
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=`security find-identity -v -p codesigning | egrep "\d\d?\)\s[a-zA-Z0-9]{40}\s\"${SIGN_IDENTITY}\""`
```

`security find-identity -v -p codesigning` return value looks like:

```
1) code_signing_id_40_alphanumeric "iPhone Distribution: My Company (alphanumeric)"
2) code_signing_id_40_alphanumeric "iPhone Developer: My Company (alphanumeric)"
```

As shown, `SIGN_IDENTITY` can have characters like `)` or `.` that are especial characters in regex and need to be replaced with `\)` (or in this case `\\)`). I did some search to find if somebody else had a similar issue and if there exists a function that does this job, but couldn't find anything.

I'm also new to Bash. Looking for an existing function or a way to replace `SIGN_IDENTITY` regex related characters to string literals.

One way that is suggested and can be used is as follow:

```
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=`security find-identity -v -p codesigning | grep -F "${SIGN_IDENTITY}"`
```

But I'm curious to know if there's a way to escape the especial characters from `SIGN_IDENTITY` and use it as part of a regex pattern.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, but if you are open to using Perl-compatible regular expressions (either `grep -P` or `pcregrep`), you can use the `\Q` and `\E` escapes to enable literal processing of characters between them.

Comment: As an aside -- all-caps variable names are used by variables with meaning to the shell or operating system, whereas the namespace containing at least one lower-case character is reserved for application use. Consider sticking inside the latter set to prevent any chance of overwriting variables meaningful to the shell or OS by accident.

Comment: BTW, not much in your sample data *needs* to be escaped. Parenthesis, for instance, are special in ERE or PCRE, but not BRE (which is what `grep` uses by default). The periods are single-character wildcards, sure, but how likely is it there's a `My Great Company, INC!` that you need to avoid matching?

Comment: ...on a different note, by the way, `\d` and `\s` are PCRE extensions -- they're not in ERE, which is the standard that `egrep` is guaranteed to support. Use `[[:digit:]]` and `[[:space:]]` for compatibility.

Comment: Your `SIGN_IDENTITY="..My Great Company..."` and `security find-identity` returns without `Great`. No match here?

Comment: That is funny. I posted an answer to this question suggesting the use of `grep -F`, which at the time was not mentioned on the question at all and was (I believe) a good answer, but now my answer disappeared?? Did someone on SO deleted my answer? Can someone fill me in on what happened to my answer?

Comment: @JamilSaid Yeah, that was a simpler version of it and it was marked as duplicate so I couldn't change and update it with this more details version. Sorry for the trouble : )

Comment: Oh, you reposted the question with modifications. OK, that explains it, thanks.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Aww cool, thanks for pointing it out. Pretty new to Bash so appreciate it a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# a shell function using sed to escape POSIX BRE (Basic Regular Expressions)
bre_escape() { sed 's/[.[\*^$]/\\&/g'; }

# ...and an example of its use:
sign_identity="iPhone Distribution: My Great Company, INC. (Alphanumeric_Here)"
sign_identity_re=$(bre_escape <<<"$sign_identity")
code_sign_identity=$(security find-identity -p codesigning | grep -e "$sign_identity_re")
```

Note that `bre_escape` is valid for, well, BRE -- plain `grep`, not `egrep` or `grep -E` or `grep -P`.

Comment: `'s/[.[\*^$]/\\&/g'` => missing `]`?

Comment: @codeforester, you don't need to escape `]` if you escaped the opening `[`.

Comment: Charles, do you mind to break down (explain) your `sed 's/[.[\*^$]/\\&/g'`? I can find it on my own, but it would never be as complete and thorough as your explanation.